# How to implement KdTree using PCLPointCloud2 used in loadOBJfile in point cloud library?

Tags: point-cloud-library, kdtree

Okay, so I have one OBJ file which I read into PCLpointcloud2. Now I want to feed it into a K-dTree. Which is not taking PCLPointCloud2 as input. I want to query any general point if it lies on the surface of my OBJ file.
I am finding it hard to understand their documentation. So how can it be done?
Plus, kindly point me to a good reference easily interpretable. And what is "PointT" BTW? Is it custom build type defined by us? please elaborate.

Comment: Does the OBJ file you are loading contain all the points that you have on the surface of your object or only vertices between which you are hoping point cloud library will interpolate?

Comment: So I am hoping PCL should interpolate the points, if possible. Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code in the provided tool `pcl_mesh_sampling` (in the PCL code directory under `tools/mesh_sampling.cpp`). It is relatively simple. It loads a model from PLY or OBJ then for each triangle it samples random points from the triangle. The final point cloud then undergoes a voxel-grid sample to make the points relatively uniform. Alternatively, you can just run the `pcl_mesh_sampling` program on your obj file to get an output PCD which you can then visualise with `pcl_viewer` before loading the PCD file into your own code.

Once you have the final point cloud, you can build and use a KD-Tree as per http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/kdtree_search.php

`PointT` is the template argument. The point cloud library can handle a variety of point types, from simple PointXYZ (having just x,y,z) to more complicated points like PointXYZRGBNormal (having x,y,z,normal_x,normal_y,normal_z, curvature, r, g, and b channels). Each algorithm is templated on the point type that you want to use. It would probably be easier if you used PointXYZ with your OBJ file, so use pcl::PointXYZ for all your template arguments. For more on templates see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_templates.htm and http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/adding_custom_ptype.php.

**Update (reply to latest comment)**

Added here because this reply is too long for a comment.

I think I see what you are getting at. So when you sample points from the point cloud & build a KD-tree of the object surface, and for each point you keep track which faces are nearby that point (probably all the faces adjacent to the face from which the point was sampled should be sufficient? Just one face is definitely insufficient). Then when the query point is given, you find the nearest point in the KD-tree and check whether the query point is on the "outside" or inside of the full list of nearby faces associated with that point in the KD-tree. If it's on the "inside" of all of them perhaps it is an interior point. But I cannot guarantee that this is true. That is my thinking on that question at the moment. But I do wonder if you want a mesh-based approach really. By the way, if you break your mesh up into convex parts then you can have nice guarantees when processing each convex part.

Comment: One more thing, if I query a kd-tree and retrieve a set of points, now for a test point we have to check if it lies inside or outside of our object just by looking these retrieved points.

Comment: Just to be clear, you have an additional requirement that you want to check to see whether a given query point is inside or outside the object? This is in addition to finding nearby points on the surface, right? I have another question: why are you converting your object into a point cloud and not just comparing any query point to each facet?

Comment: Yes, these are exactly my requirements. But my query point would be constantly changing by user input through keyboard, and the number of facets that i will have to check for every new position of query point would be huge. That is why I need to retrieve a subset of vertices at a time.

Comment: Replied in the answer.

Comment: So what I need is a data structure which takes a vertex and return the faces associated with it. So I am thinking MAPs in C++ but it would be too slow. Or what I could do is augment each point in KD-Tree with an index to the array containing faces. But then again vertex might be associated with multiple number of faces. What other methods could be used?

Comment: Since you are using the point cloud library to build the KD-Trees, why don't you use a custom point type? http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/adding_custom_ptype.php

Comment: Note that it wouldn't generally do to use variable length data structures in point clouds so you would do something like augment the point data structure with an index into a separate vector of vectors of ints.

Comment: Or i could just use Vertex normal instead. So I check my direction of change in query point and if its in opposite direction of retrieved points vertex normal then I shouldn't let query point move in that direction. Would it work?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by letting a query point "move". Note that if you just look at the vertex normals, you have to look at several of them usually.

Comment: I was hoping to find nearby points using KDtree, and using their index I will retrieve respective vertex normal. Thus, finding the direction of the surface.

Comment: See, my problem is to move a ball(my query point) around or along a surface. Now the ball is allowed freely but not allowed to submerged in the surface. Thus all this work.

Comment: You cannot just look at one vertex normal because it does not tell you enough about the local surfaces. How far behind the normal does the ball have to be for it to be inside? Note that there are some techniques in game physics that can speed up this kind of calculation (I assume that you're introducing all this complexity because you've already tried the calculations on the polygons and they've proved too slow?). E.g. sweep & prune. It should be better motivated than converting to a point cloud.

Comment: NO no. Please tell me the simplest thing I can do and I will implement. Please in details or guide me in direction .

Comment: Is your big shape convex or is it easy for you to break it up into convex parts?